# How to make a field in Serializer both readable and writeable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am writing a Serializer for my model which will be accessed using GET, POST and PATCH endpoints. I have a property in my model which I am using as a source for a field. However, using `source=` in serializer field is making it ready-only.

If I remove the `source="get_field1"` from the

`field1 = serializers.NullBooleanField(source="get_field1")`

then I am able to update the data.

But I HAVE to use the source to get the right value of the field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = NullBooleanField(default=None)

    @property
    get_field1(self):
       data = True
       # ...some logic
       return data
```

Now I have a serializer that I am using

```
    class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        field1 = serializers.NullBooleanField(source="get_field1")
        class Meta:
             model = MyModel
             fields = ('field1')
```

Now in my API endpoint, I do this

```
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(my_model, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save() # <- throws error "can't set attribute"
```

Also, I would like to mention that the field in the serializer is referred by the property name and not by the field name.

Example: If I do

`>> serializer.validated_data`

`>> 'OrderedDict(['get_field1'], True) # <- shouldn't this by field1 and not get_field1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by @JPG is good, but I feel it's a hacky way.

I would override the `to_representation` method of the Serializer to achieve your purpose.

Here's what you can do

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        field1 = serializers.NullBooleanField() # get rid of source

        def to_representation(self, instance):
             data = super(MyModel, self).to_representation(instance)
             data.update({
                  'field1': instance.get_field1
             })
             return data       

        class Meta:
             model = MyModel
             fields = ('field1')
```

This way you are implicitly providing the source and your field becomes writeable. So every time you GET, POST, or PATCH you'll get the right value.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by overriding the **`__init__()`** method of the serializer. Apart from that, we've to pass some ***`context`*** data to the serializer to distinguish between the `GET`, `POST` and `PATCH` requests.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field1 = serializers.NullBooleanField()  # remove "source" argument from here

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            self.fields['field1'] =serializers.NullBooleanField(source= "get_field1")

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1',)
```

and while serializing the data, don't forget to pass the request as context, as

```
serializer = MyModelSerializer(my_model, data=request.data, partial=True, context={"request": request})
```

Comment: That's a cool way, but  setting it `self.fields['field1'].source = "get_field1"` way doesn't work? I do I set the source field dynamically?

Comment: Yeah... You have to set it dynamically

Comment: what's the syntax to set it dynamically? the syntax you mentioned doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't get any error, but verified, the source is still not set to what I wanted.